# ColdFusion Verity search is getting confused by "&" in a searchable field

Tags: coldfusion, field, verity

I tried looking for an example of getting around this but had no luck.  Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction!

I have a Verity Collection.  The description field of a record has a title, such as "Flowers & Candy Scented Candle"

When I type "Flowers & Candy" into a search, it returns no results.

If I type in just the word Flowers or Candy alone, it will find a result.

I am re-factoring some old code that did this through a fun and interesting sql query without use of the Verity Search engine.

Is there a quick way to get around this issue or get the Verity search to behave?

I considered enclosing the terms automatically in a quote but that might limit results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[cflib.org](http://cflib.org) is your friend.

http://www.cflib.org/udf/verityClean

Comment: Oh, CFlib, how could I forget about you.  Another wheel not re-invented. Appreciate it!